# CSS Navigation SubMenu will NOT display over Image when rolled over

Tags: html, css, z-index, nav

I have been messing with this problem for about 4 days. I have read all kinds of forum posts on it, but nothing I've tried has worked. Here is my situation. I have a CSS Navigation Menu. Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, and on most of my pages in IE it is fine. But if the submenu drop down menu covers an image that is directly below the navigation menu, the submenu will disappear when moused over. You can see the working example in IE at the following address:

http://dcmsandbox.net/Menu.html

Please view source on IE to view code.

I would appreciate any help on this as I cannot figure it out on my own. I think it has something to do with z-index, but any combination I've used has failed.

Thank you.

Comment: You have some invalid HTML you may want to correct first http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdcmsandbox.net%2FMenu.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but using TABLES, inline FONT tags and BRs for formatting are a symptoms of someone stuck in 1999. You should really consider using modern coding techniques.

Comment: It's probably a z-index issue. Trying giving your NAV UL a higher z-index that the DIV containing the image. As @Diodeus said your code is very much out of date. Updating it would be a much better idea.

Comment: Anyone have any solutions that would work with the older code I'm using?